# Сравнение ключ словаря dict с регулярным выражением

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть словарь, в котором перечислены люди и их дни рождения в формате:

```
dni_ludi = {"Дата рождения":"ФИО", "Дата рождения":"ФИО"}
```

А также регулярное выражение, в котором вписаны нужные мне даты. Например, только те люди, которые родились с марта по апрельм(регулярка составлена правильно, проверял на онлайн интерпретаторе):

```
regular = r'(?<!\d)(?:0?|[1-3][0-9]|).(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]).(?:19[0-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне можно отсортировать **ключи** по регулярному выражению, а дальнейшем вывести и значение и ключ?

Comment: отсортировать ключи по регулярному выражению? интересно. Пробегитесь по всем ключам и просто проверьте ее регуляркой. Если что, у Вашей схемы хранения кода  будет проблема, если два человека родились в один день

Comment: {"Дата рождения":"ФИО", "Дата рождения":"ФИО"} если будут одинаковые даты рождения - перезапишутся старые записи

Comment: @Jack_oS задаю я заранее.

Comment: @KoVadim вот я хотел бы спросить, как это можно сделать "пробежаться по ключам регуляркой". Если например есть совпдаание, то выполняется действие.
Все данные я задаю заоранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
for key in dni_ludi:
    if re.findall(regular, key):
        print('Дата подходит: ', dni_ludi[key])
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы не могли бы подсказать, как можно вывести значение элемента, ключ которого совпадает?

Comment: @ArtemL. если вы имеете ввиду `ФИО`, то добавил

Comment: `for key in dni_ludi:
    if re.findall(regular, key):
        print('Выводим дату и ФИО: ', key, " - ", dni_ludi(key))`